# error " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::_S_create "

Tags: string

I want to return a string from a function and add that string to another string, but i stumbled on this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'   what():  basic_string::_S_create
```

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

bool isTerminal(string str)
{
    if(str == "This" || str == "Computers" || str == "I" || str == "never" ||  str == "is" || str == "run" || str == "am" || str == "tell" || str =="university" || str == "world" || str == "cheese" || str == "lie")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

string subject()
{
    string subjects[3] = {"This ", "Computers ", "I "};
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = rand() % 3;
    cout << subjects[i];
}

string verb()
{
    string verbs[4] = {"is ","run ","am ","tell "};
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = rand() % 4;
    return verbs[i];
}

string noun(){
    string nouns[4] = {"university ","world ","cheese ","lie "};
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = rand() % 4;
    return nouns[i];
}

string sentence(){
    string sentence="";
    string s = subject();
    string v = verb();
    string n = noun();

    sentence = s + v + n ;
    cout << sentence << endl;
}

int main()
{
    sentence();
    return 0;
}
```

I am basically new to programming and I would like to know what the error means. I looked up on many sites but it seemed no one has the same problem as I did. I want to randomly return a subject, a verb and a noun to form a sentence.Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Can you add a return statement for both ```subject()``` and ```sentence()```? I'm not sure if that was the exact solution but it will help eliminate other errors

Comment: thank you so much, I was trying to debug with the vscode debugger but it didn't work with string then I used cout to see how it worked and then I forgot the return, how stupid I am.